# Image not uploading in server for magento

Tags: image, magento, upload

I have some  issues in uploading picture in server for magento,but its working fine in local host.In server its not uploading

please find a solution for this,please reply as soon as possible

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error or what ? check write permissions on filesystem - especially media folder

Comment: media folder permission is 705

Comment: Try to rename your .htaccess file inside the /media directory to .htaccess-old. This will absolutely resolve your image issue.